# JDBC process seems stopped when running in docker container

Tags: java, spring, docker, apache-camel, spring-jdbc

I have a simple java test app implemented with Apache Camel 2.17.0

```
<camelContext id="txn-route-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="partnerToDB-route">
        <from uri="jms001:queue:camelInAction.sample.partners?username=admin&password=" />
        <transacted />
        <bean ref="partner" method="toSql" />
        <to uri="jdbc:testoracledb001" />
        <log message="Finished running SQL...wait for program exit..."></log>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

The route read a message from jms queue, contruct insert SQL statement using "partner" bean "toSQL" method, then call JDBC endpoint to run the insert statement through JDBC, write a log message, and then exit.

This Java program runs without issue if I package it as a runnable jar and run it directly using "java -jar ..."

Then I package the runnable jar in a alpine java docker image and then run it inside docker container. Note that I'm on a Win7 PC running Docker-Machine

```
docker build -t "alpine:Java8" .
docker run alpine:Java8 java -jar /jdbctest/jdbctest.jar
```

The first docker run is okay... but if I repeat the same docker run command for several times, there would be chance that the process stuck at the JDBC endpoint until timeout...

```
20160401 10:00:49,752[camelInAction.sample.partners]] EndpointMessageListener        WARN  Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket]    
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1680)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionErrorHandler.java:190)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:34)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
at org.apache.camel.spring.spi.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:176)
```

when the issue happened once, it is repeatable if I perform docker run again. If I remove docker image, rebuild the image and perform docker run, the program will resume to normal until I run it multiple times.

I cannot see any further logs or errors for investigation... Would like to seek any advice for further investigation

Supplement with some Dockerfile content

```
FROM alpine:3.3

#...curl and apk commands to install Jdk8... skip here

ENV JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME} \
    PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
VOLUME /jdbctest
COPY ./jdbctest.jar /jdbctest/
```

Supplement with my Spring JDBC connection config

```
<bean id="db001" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="URL" value="${db001.url}" /> 
    <property name="user" value="${db001.username}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${db001.password}"/> 
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/> 
</bean>
```

Some more tests done:

1) use centos:latest as base image instead of alpine linux... I can repeat docker run for about 4-5 times, but then got the "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket"... issue disappear if I re-build the docker image and "docker run" again

2) "docker rm" all containers I can found in "docker ps -a" before each re-run, the same issue was found.

3) Test by connecting another Oracle DB server... the same issue still happens. Oracle DB version is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit. I'm using the ojdbc6.jar jdbc driver.

4) If I run the same jar without wrapping it inside a docker container, the issue did not happen